# tensorrt not support: tf.unpack, tf.slice, tf.tile, tf.expand_dims, tf.fill, tf.cast, tf.floor_div, tf.range

Tags: tensorflow, tensorrt

There are lots of unsupported operation for tensorrt when convert from tensorflow model to uff model ( such as: `tf.unpack, tf.slice, tf.tile, tf.expand_dims, tf.fill, tf.cast, tf.floor_div, tf.range`). Is there a simple method to solve the problem?
This is the warnings when i convert convert from pb to uff model:

```
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Unpack yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Unpack yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Unpack yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: FloorDiv yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: FloorDiv yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Range yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Range yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Range yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Range yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Range yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Range yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Range yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Range yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Range yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Range yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: ExpandDims yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Fill yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Slice yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Range yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Tile yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Cast yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Range yet.
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Unpack yet.
```

Comment: There is no "simple method", TensorRT supports a relatively small subset of all TensorFlow operations, so you have to restrict your model to those if you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [TF-TRT](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/dgx/integrate-tf-trt/index.html) which allows to convert only the part of the graph that's supported by TRT, and leave the rest in TF. You can find some examples here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorrt